# What is the statement to update data in one table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to update a column in one table with data from another.

I have a table called `MVPR` with a column called `A2` and a prefix column called `C`.

I want to to replace all the data in `A2` with data from a table called `Stock` where the data I want to use is in `Lat`. I need to do this for a bunch of part #'s in the database. The part # column in the `MVPR` table is called `Part` and in the `Stock` table it's called `Subkey1`.

So basically I want to update the `A2` cost in `MVPR` where prefix = 'C' and `Subkey1 like 'FEL%'`  with the cost from the `LAT` column in the `Stock` table.

Sorry if I'm not phrasing this correctly. I'm still new to SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
update MVPR
set A2 = LAT
from MVPR inner join Stock 
on MVPR.Part = Stock.Subkey1
where MVPR.Prefix = 'C'
AND Stock.Subkey1 LIKE 'FEL%'
```